# Force scroll down to a particular point after some user scrolling [React]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Once a user scrolls down to a particular point on a page i'd like javascript to kick in and force the scroll to a particular point below that.

**For example, if I have 2 divs placed one on top of each other, once the user has scrolled 50% through the first div i'd like some animation to kick in and scroll them down to the starting point of the next div.**

Does anyone know how to do this using React?  I've found lots of packages that let me do this by having the user click a button but I want it to happen automatically in response to their scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS `scroll snapping` functionality to do what you want.
it's really easy to set up :)

Here a lick to a tutorial : [Scroll snapping CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)

And here is a nice short video that demonstrate it directly : [Scroll snapping video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pohyK8iz-SQ)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect the percentage of an element that is visible and trigger a callback that would set scrolltop on the desired element. Or use the `element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});` if you want to animate the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way for you in React 16 would be using an intersection observer (like `react-intersection-observer`) and a couple of refs(or you could use some dedicated packages). 
The code would be something among these lines:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

export default props => {
    const refToScroll = React.useRef();
    // be sure to check out all the options available
    const [refFromScroll, refFromScrollVisible] = useInView();

    useEffect(() => {
        // as soon as refFromScroll is visible, your scroll logic fires
        if(refFromScrollVisible && refToScroll.current) {
            // add more options as you like
            refToScroll.current.scrollIntoview({behavior: "smooth"})
        }
    }, [refFromScrollVisible, refToScroll.current]);

    return (<div>
        {/*as soon as it is visible your scrolling logic will be executed*/}
        <div ref={refFromScroll} />
        {/*your other components*/}
        {/*scroll to this div*/}
        <div ref={refToScroll} />    
    </div>)
}
```

You could use any other similiar package (`react-use-visibility`) or even write your own hook or component which will call `element.getBoundingClientRect()`, detect if any of its properties (`top`,`left`,`bottom`, `right`) are positive and less than windows `height` and `width` (assuming you are looking to check if it's visible at all, you can totally use another element as visibility boundary) and fire a callback or fill flag once it's visible (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) for reference). Personally I like `react-intersection-observer` the most since it's react-tuned and pretty customizable on top of that.